# How to display a BLOB image that is taken from database in the imageview?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, blob

I stored the image as BLOB in database and i fetched it using the following coding

```
const char*dbPath=[databasePath UTF8String];
if (sqlite3_open(dbPath, &sqliteHandler)==SQLITE_OK) {
    sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
    NSString *selctQuery=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from imagetable where imageId=11"];
    NSLog(@"selectQuery is %@",selctQuery);
    const char *dispStmt=[selctQuery UTF8String];       
    sqlite3_prepare_v2(sqliteHandler, dispStmt, -1, &stmt, NULL);
    NSLog(@"%d",sqlite3_prepare_v2(sqliteHandler, dispStmt, -1, &stmt, NULL));

    while (sqlite3_step(stmt)==SQLITE_ROW) {
        //  NSString *pwd=[[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(sqltmt, 1)];
    //  NSString *image1=[[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 1)];
    //  NSString *image2=[[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 2)];
    //  NSString *image3=[[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 3)];
        //NSLog(@"%@",image1);
        NSData *cachedImage1 = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:sqlite3_column_blob(stmt, 1) length: sqlite3_column_bytes(stmt, 1)];           
        NSData *cachedImage2 = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:sqlite3_column_blob(stmt, 2) length: sqlite3_column_bytes(stmt, 2)];           
        NSData *cachedImage3 = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:sqlite3_column_blob(stmt, 3) length: sqlite3_column_bytes(stmt, 3)];           

        thumbImage = [UIImage imageWithData:cachedImage1];
        bgImage = [UIImage imageWithData:cachedImage2];
        logoImage = [UIImage imageWithData:cachedImage3];
        [cachedImage1 release];
        [cachedImage2 release];
        [cachedImage3 release];

    }
}
```

I tried to display using the following code...

```
bCardFront.image=[UIImage imageNamed:bgImage]
```

but it dispays the warning message that says

> incompatible Objective-C types 'struct UIImage *', expected 'struct NSString *' when passing argument 1 of 'imageNamed:' from distinct Objective-C type

Can anyone please tell me how to display this images in separate imageviews.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bCardFront.image=[UIImage imageNamed:bgImage]` replace to

`bCardFront.image=bgImage`  here bgImage is not image name it is object of UIImage

Comment: i tried this , but its not working. And also not displaying any errors. The app just quits out.

Comment: I stored manually and not through code... I am sure that images are fetched correctly. Because when i try to set background image for button its working , but the same image is not working in ImageViews.

Comment: @iPhone_suren then check bCardFront initiation and also check  to set image for bundle if it work then tell

Answer (score 0):

[UIImage imagedNamed:xxx] will take image from your app bundle and xxx is a string for the image name. Try this:

```
[bCardFront setImage:bgImage];
```

Comment: i tried this , but its not working. And also not displaying any errors. The app just quits out.